# C# WPF How to create a generic method that can create a specific Window

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, types

I currently have this method in my App.Xaml.Cs project:

```
private void ApplicationStart(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
            Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

            var NetworkConnectionView = new NetworkConnectionView();
            NetworkConnectionView.ShowDialog();

            if (NetworkConnectionView.ConnectionNetWorkServerInternetState == ConnectionStatus.NetworkConnectionSuccess)
            {
                var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
                Current.MainWindow = mainWindow;
                mainWindow.Show();
            }

            else if(NetworkConnectionView.ConnectionNetWorkServerInternetState == ConnectionStatus.NetworkConnectionFail)
            {
                NetworkErrorView networkErrorWindow = new NetworkErrorView();
                networkErrorWindow.ShowDialog();
                Current.Shutdown(-1);
            }
}
```

I would like to be able to outsource all its content in a static method contained in a library. Like this :

```
private void ApplicationStart(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    NetWorkTools.MyExternalMethod();
}
```

But I don't know how to do it because `MainWindow` only exists in my main WPF project ( and also `Current`). All other method/class are created from my Library, so I wouldn't have a problem referencing them.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking is. Should the window be created in the library or the startup code? in OnStartup, you say you already have a main window (`the mainwindow of this project`), so what should the method do?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I want to create it in my library and not in OnStartup method.

Comment: So why does the method have a parameter (`the mainwindow of this project`), what does it mean?

Comment: It was just to try to make my idea clearer. I 've corrected my post

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea of what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: If none of the above mentioned examples apply to your question, then the question may don't belong on stackoverflow, see [help] and [tour]

Comment: @Kilazur  Sorry, I've re edited my post, hoping it will be clearer.

Comment: Where will mainwindow be? This is still supposed to be mainwindow in your calling project or it's configurable or it's in your library... or what? And. NetworkErrorView. This is to be in your control library your new generic method is in. The one that will save you pasting 16 lines of code per solution.

Comment: @Andy the mainwindow will be in the calling project, and NetworkErrorView is already in my Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be generic, then do it like this:

```
private void ApplicationStart<TWindow>() where TWindow : Window, new()
{
   ...
   Application.Current.MainWindow = new TWindow();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you're trying to "start" the Mainwindow from another function. This works for all "Windows" by first creating an instance of them and then showing them as well.

```
Mainwindow mw = new Mainwindow();
mw.show();
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)